# How to trick this Matlab MEX to read a function again?

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm using a closed-source MEX function, so I don't know this works behind the scenes. I supply it a function name as a string, and the MEX calls this function repeatedly with a long delay (seconds to minutes). While developing, I'd like to change my supplied function without restarting the MEX function.

```
the_MEX_function( 'my_function' );
```

I've tried this:

- just editing `my_function`
- calling `my_function_2` from `my_function`, and editing `my_function_2`

Do you have any ideas of what else could work?

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why calling `my_function_2` from `my_function` doesn't work. This seems like the right strategy, but `my_function` should clear `my_function_2` before execution during development to ensure it is reloaded; so, either from the command line or within `my_function`, include:

```
clear my_function_2
```

Remove this in production code to avoid a significant performance hit.

Answer (score -1):

Before calling the mex for the first time

1. Make a text file that contains the code you want (better a single line). This should decide what `my_function` does.
2. Change `my_function` to do the following read the text file and `eval` the code there.
3. Run the mex file with `my_function`
4. During the mex execution, you may change the contents of the txt file to point `my_function` to different code.

Not a very good practice, though...